# PHP websockets - Address already in use

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to set up PHP websockets on my website. This works great on my local WAMP server, but on my website I keep getting a warning:

> unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in"

I tried various libraries, but they all return this error.

My guess is that the port I'm using in isn't free. The problem is, that I cannot access terminal since this is a shared server (according to phpinfo() websockets are enabled, btw) so I can't look for free ports. Also tried to use port 0 - but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
For instance, this is some code using https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

```
// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], 9300);
```

Well, Bluehost site writes: "We block access to certain ports to help avoid having security holes in the firewall...Purchasing a dedicated IP will allow us to grant you access to the ports you will need to run your specific services on.". The technical support guy told me otherwise. I guess case is closed. Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Normally you have to be a privileged user to use a port below 10000. Since it's  shared host it's unlikely you have the privileges so I suppose it's possible to get that error message. Try a port above 10000 and see if it works.

Comment: I get the same error :'(

Comment: There are up to 65,535 ports. Anything in the lower numbers will likely be in use. How many have you tried? Try lots of random ports above 40000 to see if you still get the error.

Comment: @Cfreak below 10000? I think you mean't 1024. Or is host specific?

Comment: Well, I tried a few. I'll keep trying, but as for now, nothing is working. It might not be ports problem... I'm using $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] for the IP. Is it OK?

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to a virtual server package so that you can run your own services. You need dedicated server. At least virtual.

Comment: Your webserver can not use ports below 1024 as listening sockets, because it's not running as user root. No sane provider would run a webserver as root. This affects all linux servers. That's why it works on your WAMP installation.

Comment: I'm trying to check wheater the hosting blocked this option or not. Anyway, thank you all for your time and dedication!

Comment: According to them, fsockopen is enabled on shared servers as well

Comment: @JimmyKane yes you're right. I had 10000 in my mind for some reason. It is indeed 1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your hosting provider has, somehow, disabled PHP sockets. This makes sense because PHP is used to process webpages not create daemons and you're probably using a regular web hosting plan (not a dedicated server).

I would check in with your hosting provider - support forum or just call them.

Comment: Even when phpinfo() says sockets are enabled?

Comment: It could be a firewall blockade. Even if you do manage to establish a socket and a daemon therefore, eventually they'll find out and stop your scripts.
Also, do check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778056/php-websocket-on-webserver

Comment: Well, they say fsockopen works on shared servers as well. Not sure what it means

Comment: Can you post the actual code that creates the socket connection (be it your custom or library initiated code)?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

talhof9 I went through similar pain in trying to configure my shared hosting service, I didn't find a direct solution to get a shared *AMP server to support WebSockets, but I found a workaround that will at least let you test the commercial viability of the solution you are putting together (if that is indeed what you are looking for) without paying for all the headache of setting up,configuring and administering your own VPS.

Check out http://www.pusher.com for an easy websocket deployment library, that uses their Node server. The free sandbox version lets you play around to get it working, and once you want to test commercial viability you can upgrade to a paid plan.

Hope this helps!

(note I **do not** work for Pusher)