# PHP WebSocket Client? Or way to run JavaScript inside of PHP (without a browser)? Hopefully with Ratchet

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

I'm very new to WebSockets and have been playing with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) and gotten a simple chat room to work on my AWS EC2 instance.  Now I'm trying to use another service which can run a custom PHP script (hosted on their servers) to open a websocket connection on my server and send a message.

I got the EC2 URL working, and when I run it in my browser (including on my phone, which isn't on the same network as my computer) it works.  I'm simply passing a testing API key and the value in the URL for now (grabbed with PHP GET), like so:

http://ec2-22-222-22-222.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/path/to/script/ws-trigger.php?key=12345&name=Bing

This works, but only because the `ws-trigger.php` page loads the following JavaScript and runs it from the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://22.222.22.222:8080');
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
        conn.send(<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>);
    };
</script>
```

What is the easiest way for me to run this "connect to the websocket" and "send a message over the socket" via PHP?  If I have to use a library I'd prefer use Ratchet since I already am, but I feel like I must be missing something because this cannot be a unique problem.

I have tried searching StackOverflow already, but have had issues with the few answers I'd already found (like [phpwebsocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778056/php-websocket-on-webserver) was giving me troubles before I moved to Ratchet, and [this one isn't a PHP WS client at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php))

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP as a websocket client, because PHP is stateless it would only do things on requests anyway, which is the exact opposite of the purpose of websockets (a 2 way persistent connection). I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: I'm integrating to a third party who lets me run a PHP script on their server.  That script never results in browser-read HTML or JavaScript, so I cannot push the data from that service to mine via JavaScript, only PHP.  I need the events they push to trigger live-pops on the screen of every user who is logged in, so WebSocket pushes seem a much better solution than Ajax polling.

Comment: Ah, I see, I can't see a way around it then. Try the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php?lq=1) maybe. It seems Ratchet doesn't have a client built in.

Comment: Yeah, of those 4 answers 1 is "Ratchet" (which, as the reply says, lacks a WebSocket client), one is highly unstable, another lacks a client and the last one gives me pause, though I may try it if no one has any better solutions.  I actually linked to this question in the last paragraph of my own question already.  Thanks though!

Comment: Oops, well good luck, you could always write one yourself, especially if you only need limited functionality. Figure out which protocol you want to use, and find the spec for it.